# Why $\mathbb{N} \not\in \mathbb{N}$ ($\mathbb{N}$ is a set (not a number) and $\mathbb{N}$ contains only numbers)?

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

I am currently reading 'Book of Proof' by Hammack, and in the section on subsets, there is an example stating that $\mathbb{N} \not\in \mathbb{N}$ because '$\mathbb{N}$ is a set (not a number), and $\mathbb{N}$ contains only numbers. As someone new to these concepts, I find it challenging to intuitively grasp why a set cannot be an element of itself.

Does this mean that for a set $A = \{ 1,2,3,4 \}, A$ is not an element of $A$, but a set containing $A$ $(A = \{ 1,2,3,4,A \})$ could be an element of $A$? Or is it more accurate to say that the ordered tuple $(1,2,3,4) \in A$ is not equal to the set ${1,2,3,4} \in A$?

Comment: The issue is not that sets can’t be elements of themselves. It’s that the set $\mathbb N$ consists exactly of the natural numbers and $\mathbb N$ itself is not a natural number.

Comment: (It’s true that in the most common approach to set theory, sets are not allowed to be elements of themselves, but there are approaches where it is allowed, and in any event, this issue is completely irrelevant to this example.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must be misunderstanding the example. The assertion that $\mathbb N$ is not an element of $\mathbb N$ follows immediately from a definition:

> $\mathbb N$ is the set whose elements are exactly the natural numbers.

and a reasonable assertion:

> $\mathbb N$ is not a natural number.

Why is this latter assertion true? The author's argument is that $\mathbb N$ is just a completely different kind of thing: it's a set not a number, so of course it's not a natural number.

That's a perfectly acceptable argument at this level of detail. When we make things more precise about what the natural numbers actually "are" we can get a more precise justification, perhaps with a formal type system where $\mathbb N$ is not of type $\mathbb N.^1$

Nowhere in the author's justification is it stated that a set cannot be an element of itself. And it's perfectly possible that a set can be. For instance, in systems of set theory that have a universal set (i.e. the set of all sets), of course the universal set must be an element of itself.

In the most common formal set theory (ZFC) it is the case that no set is allowed to be an element of itself. Nor is a set containing $A$ as an element allowed to be an element of $A$, and this goes on for any number of layers of containment. This is a consequence of the axiom of regularity$.^{2}$

But, again, this issue of whether a set can in principle have itself as a member is completely irrelevant to the example and the author's justification for it.

---

$^1$ Very minor note: we could maybe dream up a wacky set theory formalization where it *is* the case that $\mathbb N\in \mathbb N$... set theory notoriously has no formal type system to enforce common sense reasoning of sort the author is making. But also set theory will never force a given pathology of this sort on us and indeed every approach I've ever seen of formalizing the natural numbers in set theory satisfies $\mathbb N\notin \mathbb N$.

---

$^{2}$ The reason ZFC has regularity as an axiom isn't really due to some philosophical principle that a set *can't* be an element of itself (or at least that's not how most people think of it), but just that we never actually need to consider these 'irregular' sets in order to do ordinary mathematics and that it makes the universe of sets easier to understand if we just get rid of them.

Answer (score 1):

First an informal approach:

Consider a set $A$, and some element $x$. We say $x \in A$ if and only if we can find $x$ inside of $A$. We do *not* want to find $\{x\}$ in $A$, because $\{x\} \not = x$.

Back to our problem at hand, we want to know why  $\mathbb{N} \not \in \mathbb{N}$. It is true that all of the elements of $\mathbb{N}$ are in $\mathbb{N}$, but since $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$, we don't see $\mathbb{N}$ in here.

Formally: Let $A = \{y: S(y)\}$, where $S(y)$ is some statement about $y$
, and y is an element of $A$ if and only if $S(y)$ is true (if $ S(n) = n \text{ is an even number}$ then it would be true for any even number). Then we say $x \in A \Leftrightarrow S(x)$.

Then, we define $\mathbb{N}  = \{n : \text{n is a positive integer or $0$}\}$. As $\mathbb{N}$ is not a positive integer or 0, we can safely say $\mathbb{N} \not \in \mathbb{N}$.

Final note on this that many people get mistaken on, $x \not = \{x \}$. This feels obvious, but for the statements $x \in A$, $\{x \} \in A$ are different. This may be where your confusion lies, because every natural number is in the natural numbers, but the set of all natural numbers is not a natural number. Also, in your last sentence you say that $(1,2,3,4) \in A$, in my opinion (I may be wrong) this is incorrect, since $(1,2,3,4)$ is called the $4\text{-tuple}$, or an ordered pair. You should say $1,2,3,4 \in A$, to say that the numbers $1,2,3,4$ are all in $A$. A different way of saying it you may see: $\forall i \in \{1,2,3,4\}, i \in A$, which I only mention as you say you are reading proofs from the book.

Comment: I offer a couple of clarifications.
$1, 2, 3, 4 \in A$ is an abbreviation for *$1 \in A, 2 \in A, 3 \in A$ and $4 \in A$*.

(1, 2, 3, 4) can mean a couple of things.  It could be a 4-tuple; 4-tuples are very similar to ordered pairs, except they have 4 numbers instead of two numbers.   Imagine the traditional 3 dimensions, plus a 4th number such as time, temperature or color.  That could be (x, y, z, temperature) or (x, y, z, time)

Occasionally, (1, 2, 3, 4) will be used for set notation, meaning (1, 2, 3, 4) = {1, 2, 3, 4}, but in my opinion using (, ) for set notation is a bit sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

In set theory, natural numbers are constructed from the empty set $\varnothing$ as follows.  $0$ corresponds to $\varnothing$, $1$ corresponds to $\{0\}$, $2$ corresponds to $\{0,1\}$, etc.  There is a notion of von Neumann rank that is helpful to make the necessary distinctions here.  For a natural number $n$, the von Neumann rank of $n$ equals precisely $n$.  Now the entity $\mathbb N$ is defined is the smallest inductive set.  It contains all the natural numbers and its von Neumann rank is $\omega$ (which is infinite).  So one way to see that $\mathbb N \not\in\mathbb N$ is that $\mathbb N$ has infinite von Neumann rank, whereas $\mathbb N$ contains only elements of finite von Neumann rank.